# How to I add DateTime to my existing database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET / C# / Visual Studio and I'm currently working on a Casus to learn the language and ASP.NET MVC.

I've created two tables in my database and I would like to add a column to my existing `Reviews` table. Normally I would just update my model then run `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` in the Package Manager Console, however this time I'm getting the following error:

> No mapping to a relational type can be found for property 'cmsEen.Models.Review.ReviewPostTime' with the CLR type 'DateTime'.

In my `Review` model, I've added:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ReviewPostTime { get; set; }
```

The complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cmsEen.Models
{
    public class Review
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReviewId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(0, 5)]
        [Display(Name = "Rating:")]
        public int ReviewRating { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title:")]
        public string ReviewTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Message:")]
        public string ReviewMessage { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ReviewPostTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If anyone has a solution or could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Try deleting the line [DataType(DataType.Date)]. EF will figure out the correct [SQL data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Pro Tip: it is not Date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`. When using entity framework and migrations you will not need to specify the sql data type. Generally when you add a `DateTime` object and `add-migration` it will save the data type in the database as a `datetime2` type.

Answer (score 1):

The "datetime" field in the database SQL does not fit into the "DateTime" type of the CLR. You need to either convert or use the "datetime 2" type.

[datetime2 (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

And perhaps the text representation of the date will have to be brought to your format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"